# Is this actually correlation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

[image]

Is this misusing correlation? Am I being silly?

maybe it would only be a correlation if there were multiple pictures of cats being on broken roofs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/48l3ee.gif

Answer (score 1):

Not really; it's more of a coincidence.  Correlation would be something like walking around town and seeing lots of roofs where most of the ones that are crushed have a cat on top, and most of the ones that are not, don't.

In other words, "correlation" is a pattern of association across many observations of a pair of variables. A single observation isn't enough to establish a correlation (let alone a causation).